# GraphQL Expected Iterable, but did not find one for field xxx.yyy

Tags: node.js, graphql, graphql-js

I'm currently trying GraphQL with NodeJS and I don't know, why this error occurs with the following query:

```
{
  library{
    name,
    user {
      name
      email
    }
  }
}
```

I am not sure if the `type` of my `resolveLibrary` is right, because at any example I had a look at they used `new GraphQL.GraphQLList()`, but in my case I really want to return a single user object, not an array of users.

My code:

```
const GraphQL = require('graphql');
const DB = require('../database/db');
const user = require('./user').type;

const library = new GraphQL.GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'library',
    description: `This represents a user's library`,
    fields: () => {
        return {
            name: {
                type: GraphQL.GraphQLString,
                resolve(library) {
                    return library.name;
                }
            },
            user: {
                type: user,
                resolve(library) {
                    console.log(library.user);
                    return library.user
                }
            }
        }
    }
});

const resolveLibrary = {
    type: library,
    resolve(root) {
        return {
            name: 'My fancy library',
            user: {
                name: 'User name',
                email: {
                    email: 'test@123.de'
                }
           }
        }
    }
}

module.exports = resolveLibrary;
```

Error:

```
Error: Expected Iterable, but did not find one for field library.user.
```

So my `library` schema provides a `user` field which returns the right data (the console.log is called).

Comment: It sounds like possibly a problem with the user type you are importing. Can you update your question to include the code for `user.js`?

Comment: Thank you very much, you were right, the export of my user.js was wrong...

Comment: Show in an edit your solution please?

Answer (score 170):

I ran into this problem as well. It appears that what you're returning from your resolver doesn't match the return type in your schema.

Specifically for the error message `Expected Iterable, but did not find one for field library.user.`, your schema expects an array(Iterable) but you aren't returning an array in your resolver

I had this in my schema.js:

`login(email: String, password: String): [SuccessfulLogin]`

I changed that to:

`login(email: String, password: String): SuccessfulLogin`

Notice the square brackets around "SuccessfulLogin". It's up to you whether you want to update the resolver return type or update the schema's expectations

Comment: Hi @vineeth, thanks for the update, i have one more thing to ask, what is the square brackets for? seems fine without them

Comment: @Liang Square brackets signifies that you should be expecting an iterable object or an array in the JSON response. Apologies for late response

Comment: thanks and no worries. i think i got it now,`[]` means it shall return `array`, without, shall return `object`

Comment: Dang, I changed it for something and forgot to change it back lmao. Thanks.

Comment: data matching it is! +1

Comment: I feel guilty when reading this. Thank you for taking time to post this answer.

Comment: Cool this help to figure out my binding errors! Thanks

Comment: Thank you! I encountered the same problem. My resolver was returning an object and my schema was expecting an array.

Answer (score 10):

I guess your `user` is an instance of `GraphQLList` that is why the field user is expecting to resolve to an iterable object.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem. I was using find instead filter.

Answer (score 5):

I ran into the same issue but i was using GraphQL with Go.

**Solution:**
I mentioned the return type to be a list( or you can say an array), but my resolver function was returning an interface and not a list of interfaces.

Before it was =>

```
Type: graphql.NewList(graphqll.UniversalType)
```

Later i changed it to =>

```
Type: graphqll.UniversalType
```

**graphqll.UniversalType : 'graphqll' is the name of my user-defined package and 'UniversalType' is the GraphQL object i have created.**

The previous structure of graphql object was :

```
var GetAllEmpDet = &graphql.Field{
    Type: graphql.NewList(graphqll.UniversalType),
    Resolve: func(params graphql.ResolveParams) (interface{}, error) {
       ...
       ...
       // Your resolver code goes here, how you handle.
       ...
       return models.Universal, nil // models.Universal is struct and not list of struct so it gave that error.
    },
}
```

It worked when i changed this to:

```
var GetAllEmpDet = &graphql.Field{
    Type: graphqll.UniversalType,
    Resolve: func(params graphql.ResolveParams) (interface{}, error) {
       ...
       ...
       // Your resolver code goes here, how you handle.
       ...
       return models.Universal, nil // models.Universal is struct and not list of struct so it gave that error.
    },
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It's usually a simple mistake. Caused by declaring in the schema a **`List`** instead of a **`Field`**. The reverse will happen if you interchange. An example from `Django-graphene`. Switch from this:

```
my_query_name = graphene.List(MyModelType, id=graphene.Int())
```

to this:

```
my_query_name = graphene.Field(MyModelType, id=graphene.Int())
```

Answer (score 2):

For me, it was a simple fix.

```
 items: {
        type: new GraphQLList(VideoType),<-- error
        resolve(parentValue, args) {
            const url = 'www'

            return axios.get(url)
                .then(res => res.data);
        }
    }
```

and change it to

```
 items: {
        type: VideoType,
        resolve(parentValue, args) {
            const url = 'www'

            return axios.get(url)
                .then(res => res.data);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was related to `django-graphene` I didn't have a resolve method defined.

```py
class SomeNode(DjangoObjectType):
    things = graphene.List(ThingNode)

    def resolve_things(self, info, **kwargs):
        return self.things.all()
```

Answer (score 1):

i had the same issue i was using `findOne` and that seems like the issue that didnt worked. i changed to `find` and it worked

```js
    @Query(()=> [Post])
    async getSinglePost(
        @Arg('post_id') id: string,
    ){
        /*
        const post = await getConnection().getRepository(Post).findOne({uuid:postuid})
        console.log(post);
        return post
        */

        const post = Post.find({uuid:id})
        return post
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue. For me, it was an  issue with Mongo DB model.js file.

GraphQL kept throwing that error because my model was saving the field as an object whereas graphQL was returning it as an array.
The code that caused the error was this.

```
tableHeaders: {
            
              text: {
                type: String,
                required: false,
              },
              align: {
                type: String,
                required: false,
              },
              sortable: {
                type: Boolean,
                required: false,
              },
              value: {
                type: String,
                required: false,
              },
            
          },
```

It was corrected to the following.

```
tableHeaders: [
            {
              text: {
                type: String,
                required: false,
              },
              align: {
                type: String,
                required: false,
              },
              sortable: {
                type: Boolean,
                required: false,
              },
              value: {
                type: String,
                required: false,
              },
            },
          ],
```

Changing type from object to array fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

This simply results due to the import error
earlier code

```
const books =require('./data')
// Resolvers define the technique for fetching the types defined in the
// schema. This resolver retrieves books from the "books" array above.
const resolvers = {
    Query: {
      books(){
        return books;
    },
  },
}
module.exports = { resolvers };
```

just replace the import statement with

```
const {books} =require('./data')
```

as you had ex

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue.
For me it was,
addGame(game: AddGameInput): [Game] instead of
addGame(game: AddGameInput): Game