# GraphQL Expected Iterable, but did not find one for field while using find

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, graphql, apollo

Currently I am using Apollo/GraphQL/Node.js/Sequelize to build my backend server, and my server code looked like below, in there I can use req.user to get the current login user

```
app.use(
  '/graphql',
  bodyParser.json(),
  graphqlExpress(req => ({
    schema,
    context: {
      models,
      user: req.user,
    },
  })),
);
```

Now I have two models User and Recipe, and the association rule is Recipe belongs to User, so in the Recipe schema I can use the UserId to know which user create this schema, the Recipe schema is

```
type Recipe {
  id: Int!
  authorName: String!
  authorFbPage: String @virtual
  perfumeName: String!
  message: String
  UserId: Int
}

type Query {
  allRecipe: [Recipe]
  meRecipe: [Recipe]
  AvailableWatchRecipe: [Recipe]
}
```

My problem is in the meRecipe part, this Query supposed to be able to show the recipes created by login user, the resolver code is

```
meRecipe: async (parent, args, { models, user }) => {
      if (user) {
        console.log(user.id);
        console.log(user.username);
        return models.Recipe.find({ where: { UserId: user.id } })
          .then((result) => { return result });
      }

      return null;
    },
```

You can see I also use the console.log to check whether I can get the current user information, it actually can, so I am really confused why when I run this Query in the GraphQL server, it always shows `"message": "Expected Iterable, but did not find one for field Query.meRecipe`.
I have checked these resources:
https://github.com/brysgo/graphql-bookshelf/issues/10
and
[GraphQL Expected Iterable, but did not find one for field xxx.yyy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46513476/graphql-expected-iterable-but-did-not-find-one-for-field-xxx-yyy)
but none of them fit my case, can anyone give me some advice, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using :

```
models.Recipe.find
```

Use

```
models.Recipe.findAll // this will return single result in array
```

Comment: Hi, it worked!! Thank you so much, but why find can not do the thing that findAll do?

Comment: @yamahachou , find will return single object so not iterable , you can get that by using findAll , it will return always array of result even if it return single result.