# GraphQL Error: "Expected Iterable, but did not find one for field Query" when fetching data from CryptoCompare API

Tags: graphql, express-graphql, graphiql

I'm using GraphQL/express/express-graphql/axios to retrieve specific coin data from the CryptoCompare API.

I have two endpoints:

1) https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemultifull?fsyms=BTC,ETH,LTC,BCH,NEO,ETC,XMR&tsyms=USD

```
From endpoint 1, I want to retrieve the following in USD for 8 coins:
  - FROMSYMBOL, CHANGEPCT24HOUR, PRICE, MKTCAP, TOTALVOLUME24HTO
```

2) https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/coin/generalinfo?fsyms=BTC&tsym=USD

```
From endpoint 2, I want to retrieve the following just for Bitcoin/BTC:
  - Id, FullName, ImageUrl
```

I have setup my backend server with two files, as well as testing queries using graphiql.

File 1 - server.js

```
const express = require("express")
const graphqlHTTP = require("express-graphql")
const cors = require("cors")
const schema = require("./schema")

const app = express()

app.use(cors())

app.use(
  "/graphql",
  graphqlHTTP({
    schema,
    graphiql: true
  })
)

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000

app.listen(PORT, console.log(`✅  Listening to port ${PORT}`))
```

File 2 - schema.js

```
const {
  GraphQLObjectType,
  GraphQLList,
  GraphQLID,
  GraphQLInt,
  GraphQLString,
  GraphQLSchema
} = require("graphql")
const axios = require("axios")

const CoinDataType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: "CoinData",
  fields: () => ({
    FROMSYMBOL: { type: GraphQLString },
    CHANGEPCT24HOUR: { type: GraphQLInt },
    PRICE: { type: GraphQLInt },
    MKTCAP: { type: GraphQLInt },
    TOTALVOLUME24HTO: { type: GraphQLInt }
  })
})

const CoinInfoType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: "CoinInfo",
  fields: () => ({
    Id: { type: GraphQLID },
    FullName: { type: GraphQLString },
    ImageUrl: { type: GraphQLString }
  })
})

const Query = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: "Query",
  fields: {
    CoinData: {
      type: new GraphQLList(CoinDataType),
      resolve(parent, args) {
        return axios
          .get(
            "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemultifull?fsyms=BTC,ETH,LTC,BCH,NEO,ETC,XMR&tsyms=USD"
          )
          .then(res => res.data)
      }
    },
    CoinInfo: {
      type: new GraphQLList(CoinInfoType),
      resolve(parent, args) {
        return axios
          .get(
            "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/coin/generalinfo?fsyms=BTC&tsym=USD"
          )
          .then(res => res.data)
      }
    }
  }
})

module.exports = new GraphQLSchema({ query: Query })
```

When I use graphiql to test my queries with this:

```
{
  CoinData {
    FROMSYMBOL
  }
  CoinInfo {
    Id
  }
}
```

...I get this error:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Expected Iterable, but did not find one for field Query.CoinInfo.",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 5,
          "column": 3
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "CoinInfo"
      ]
    },
    {
      "message": "Expected Iterable, but did not find one for field Query.CoinData.",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "CoinData"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "data": {
    "CoinData": null,
    "CoinInfo": null
  }
}
```

How do I get around this error? Thanks.

Comment: Duplicate of [GraphQL Expected Iterable, but did not find one for field xxx.yyy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46513476/graphql-expected-iterable-but-did-not-find-one-for-field-xxx-yyy). What's returned in your resolver needs to match the type for the field.

Comment: Ah, I see, that makes sense. For example, in CoinInfoType, I have three fields I want to retrieve: Id/FullName/ImageUrl, but from the endpoint https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/coin/generalinfo?fsyms=BTC&tsym=USD, those fields are nested within the Data array -> CoinData object. How can I rewrite my schema to access the data? Thanks.

Comment: No need to rewrite your schema -- just manipulate the data returned by the API before returning it inside your resolver

Comment: CoinInfo: {
      type: new GraphQLList(CoinInfoType),
      resolve(parent, args) {
        return axios
          .get(
            "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/coin/generalinfo?fsyms=BTC&tsym=USD"
          )
          .then(res => res.data)
          .then(res =>
            res.Data.map(coin => {
              return {
                Id: coin.CoinInfo.Id,
                FullName: coin.CoinInfo.FullName,
                ImageUrl: coin.CoinInfo.ImageUrl
              }
            })
          )
      }
    }

This worked, but is there a more concise way?